# tkinter button in class can't call function

Tags: python, tkinter

Total noob, seriously and angrily struggling with Python...

What I'm trying to do SHOULD be simple:

1. Make a button.
2. Connect that button go a function.
3. Click button --> run function.

The problem comes when we have to use CLASS (which, no matter how much I read, study - or even pay to take classes continues to make zero sense to me)...

I've tried every concieveable combination of putting this little convert() function IN the class, of adding self.convert or root.convert - and NONE of it works. And, I am clueless why - or what to try next.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style


def convert():
    print("clicked")
    kg = entry_kg.get()
    print(kg)



class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    self.initUI()    # initiate the GUI
    # -------------------------------


    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("Weight Converter")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        # -------------------------------------

        frame_kg = Frame(self)   # frame for Kilograms
        frame_kg.pack(fill=X)

        lbl_kg = Label(frame_kg, text="Kilograms", width=16)
        lbl_kg.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        entry_kg = Entry(frame_kg)
        entry_kg.pack(fill=X, padx=(5, 30), expand=True)
        # ------------------------------------------------

        frame_btn = Frame(self)    # frame for buttons
        frame_btn.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)

        btn_convert=Button(frame_btn, text="Convert", command=convert)
        btn_convert.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        # -------------------------------------------

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200+300+200")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I doing wrong?

How to do it right?

The seemingly arbitrary and useless over-complication of a simple task is seriously maddening...

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code.

Comment: TkInter is an old interface, kept around for backward compatibility and for those who really need a self contained executable.  Modern code would use a web framework like Flask and serve a simple HTML page.  Of course that would mean learning Flask and HTML.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please try to provide a [mcve] as opposed to your current code. You'll both understand more which parts of your code does what, and improve the quality of the question to motivate better answers.

Comment: @verisimilidude I don't see how this helps the OP exactly.

Comment: Sorry to Bryan Oakley for the ugly code.

I pasted, expecting the editor to retain the indenting. 

And, seriously?  This editor not only can't maintain existing indents, but can't take tabs, either? Seriously? We have to sit and hit the spacebar?

To versimilidude (great name): Thanks very much for your comment. I'm *clueless* - I was taking a class on Udemy that said to use tkinter. Now, I'm doubly pissed-off that I've been tearing hair over this. Grateful, however for your pointing me toward Flask. Guess that's the next google...

Comment: Are you certain that `self.initUI()    # initiate the GUI` line is indented out like that?

Comment: @JohnBailey Please note that you don't _have_ to use spacebar only. You can also select the entire code and go `Ctrl - K` or use the **`{}`** button.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your functions to be designed outside of the class, but want to call it from a button defined in the class, the solution is to create a method in your class which takes the input values and then passes them to the external function.

This is called *decoupling*. Your function is *decoupled* from the implementation of the UI, and it means that you are free to completely change the implementation of the UI without changing the function, and vice versa. It also means that you can reuse the same function in many different programs without modification.

The overall structure of your code should look something like this:

```
# this is the external function, which could be in the same
# file or imported from some other module
def convert(kg):
    pounds = kg * 2.2046
    return pounds

class Example(...):
    def initUI(self):
        ...
        self.entry_kg = Entry(...)
        btn_convert=Button(..., command=self.do_convert)
        ...

    def do_convert(self):
        kg = float(self.entry_kg.get())
        result = convert(kg)
        print("%d kg = %d lb" % (kg, result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modified version of your code that works. The changes have been indicated with ALL CAPS line comments. I obviously misunderstood your question (which does say you could figure out how to make the `convert()` function part of the class. However, you mentioned you wanted the opposite of that, so I'm modified the code here accordingly.

Essentially the problem boils down to the `convert()` function needing to access a `tkinter.Entry` widget that's created somewhere else—inside your `Example` class in this case.

One way of doing that would be to save the widget in a global variable and access it through the variable name assigned to it. Many folks do that because it's easiest to thing to do, but as you should know, global variables are considered a bad practice and are generally something to be avoided.

There's a common way to avoid needing one with `tkinter`, which is sometimes called "[The extra arguments trick](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/extra-args.html)". To use it all you need to do is create a short anonymous function with an argument that has a default value defined—which in this case will be the `Entry` widget you want passed to the now "wrapped" `convert()` function. This can be done using what's called a [`lambda expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda). The revised code below and the comments in it show and describe how to do this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Style


def convert(entry_widget):  # ADDED WIDGET ARGUMENT
    """ Some function outside class. """
    print("clicked")
    kg = entry_widget.get()  # REFERENCE ENTRY WIDGET PASSED AS ARGUMENT
    print(kg)


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()    # initiate the GUI

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("Weight Converter")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        frame_kg = Frame(self)   # frame for Kilograms
        frame_kg.pack(fill=X)

        lbl_kg = Label(frame_kg, text="Kilograms", width=16)
        lbl_kg.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)

        entry_kg = Entry(frame_kg)
        entry_kg.pack(fill=X, padx=(5, 30), expand=True)

        frame_btn = Frame(self)    # frame for buttons
        frame_btn.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=5)

        btn_convert=Button(frame_btn, text="Convert",
                        # DEFINE ANONYMOUS FUNCTION WITH DEFAULT ARGUMENT SO IT'S
                        # AUTOMATICALLY PASSED TO THE TARGET FUNCTION.
                        command=lambda entry_obj=entry_kg: convert(entry_obj))
        btn_convert.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200+300+200")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: thank you for your help. Much appreciated. I wanted to keep the functions OUTside the class of the interface, but alas, that seems impossible...

Comment: John: Obviously I misunderstood what you desired. See updated answer.

Comment: thank you VERY MUCH for that update. The people here are so fantastic!  
And, boy have I got questions, now.  
You added the entry_widget argument to the def convert() function.  
If you don't mind my asking, why do we pass the widget object rather than the value contained in it?

Comment: Anyone else here hate this comment editor?  Anyone else notice it also DOES NOT WORK - does not follow the rules for formatting that the help below says it will?

Comment: Part of the line in the button function is: command=lambda entry_obj=entry_kg: convert(entry_obj)).  Why can we not just use command=lambda: convert(entry_kg.get()) ??

Comment: I'm new to Python, so please forgive me for repeating what I see others saying about the language - that it seems massively and unnecessarily long to write simple things. There are entire classes where nearly every damned line begins with self.

Comment: And, here, what in any other language I've dealt with it's just function(arg), but in Python there's all this ... stuff ... that to me means nothing (other than convoluted begging for syntax errors). Anyone have a reference for a book, video, or course that can succinctly explain to me why we're saddled with all this verbosity - and how I can come to see it as anything useful? I'm not having luck finding anything USEFUL...

Comment: John: `command=lambda: convert(entry_kg.get())` doesn't work because it calls the `convert()` function right at that moment, as the `Button` widget itself is being created, **not** later when the it's pressed (clicked-on) by the user. This is a common newbie `tkinter` programming mistake. Doing 99% of things in Python isn't terribly convoluted—if fact they're very simple to do. `tkinter` is another matter altogether and sucks in many ways, especially with regards to documentation. You may feel overwhelmed at the moment, but likely that's only frustration because you're in over your head...

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - and the encouragement, as well as the help. The explanation was very useful!

Comment: John: You're welcome. The "extra arguments trick" is exactly what one would expect from it's name: i.e. "tricky", so don't worry too much about not knowing it. At least now you'll be able to recognize when it's needed as well as how to do it. Motivated Reading's great, but only useful if there's some material to be read...

Answer (score -1):

Your `entry_kg` is not *known* anywhere outside the scope of `initUI` method. That is why. You could convert it from a method variable to instance attribute to be within reach for class methods by replacing:

```
entry_kg = Entry(frame_kg)
entry_kg.pack(fill=X, padx=(5, 30), expand=True)
```

with:

```
self.entry_kg = Entry(frame_kg)
self.entry_kg.pack(fill=X, padx=(5, 30), expand=True)
```

---

**Only *then***:

You can mention it in a class method like:

```
...
kg = self.entry_kg.get()
```

That way you if you make your `convert` a method under `Example` again:

```
def initUI(self):
...
def convert(self):           # is defined under the same scope as initUI
    print("clicked")
    kg = self.entry_kg.get() # notice that it now refers to self.e...
    print(kg)
```

also don't forget to replace command option as well:

```
btn_convert=Button(..., command=self.convert)
```

---

**Or only *then*:**

When outside the class scope, by using dot notation on the object that the class creates:

```
def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x200+300+200")
    app = Example()
    kg = app.entry_kg.get() # This would return an empty string, but it would still be valid
    root.mainloop()
```

to be used with global methods, such as the current state of `convert` you need to make `app` (the object it is an attribute of) global, or pass it explicitly to the method.

Comment: @JohnBailey There is but it is a bit messy. Do you see help link under Add Comment button? It explains a bit.

Comment: Thank you for patience.  <br/>
I've got to learn a whole new editor just to comment?<br/>  
And, that still doesn't work. NO LINE BREAKS TO BE HAD HERE

Comment: @JohnBailey Well, you don't _have_ to format your comments. But yeah, the rules here do apply in posts but not vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you again. I got the first version to work, but that locks me into putting the function IN the class - which is not the way I wanted to organize it. I wanted a class for the tkinter interface and a different place for the functions.

Comment: The instructions in the help DO NOT WORK.   
Two spaces at the end of a line do NOT create a line feed.  
Two spaces.   
Two spaces.

Comment: @JohnBailey Although it is possible, I don't think it would be a good idea to put that method outside the class. It interacts with an attribute of the class.

Comment: @JohnBailey Only the comment formatting section rules are applicable here. That link under help seems to be about general post formatting, and comment formatting but just a section under it.